# Как работает такое выражение php

Tags: php

Подскажите как работает такая строка:
$app = require('../lib/base.php');

Просто require() понятно как работает. А допустимо ли присвоить результат require переменной?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

Если во включаемом файле используется оператор `return`, то в переменную попадет результат, возвращаемый данным оператором. Если же оператора `return` нет, в переменную попадет либо `1`, либо `FALSE`, в зависимости от того, успешно ли прошло включение файла.

**file_b.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>echo from file_b</p>';
return "I'm returned from file_b";

// этот код выполнен не будет:
echo '<p>echo from file_b</p>';
```

**file_c.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>echo from file_c</p>';
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$file_b = require 'file_b.php';
$file_c = require 'file_c.php';
echo $file_b;
echo '<br />'.$file_c;

/* вывод:
echo from file_b
echo from file_c
I'm returned from file_b
1
 */
```

Стоит также отметить, что в переменную попадает именно то, что указано в `return`. Если нужно весь вывод из файла сохранить в переменную, можно использовать [буферизацию вывода](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score -1):

Еще так, например

**example.php**

```
class example
{
  public static function getEcho()
  {
    return 'Hello world';
  }

}
```

**index.php**

```
<?
require_once 'path/to/example.php';

$example = new example();
echo $example::getEcho();

?>
```

Comment: А где у ТС вопрос - Как присвоить результат reqiure переменной ? Вопрос - допустимо ли. Ему ответили выше. Я привел аналогичный пример для общего развития.

Comment: В тексте вопроса "А допустимо ли присвоить результат require переменной?". "аналогичный пример" - пример чего? Автор прекрасно понимает что делает `require`, что он почерпнет из твоего ответа?